Where do the Laws of Physics come from?
I’m having a bit of an existential crisis, and I can’t shake these questions about the universe and the laws of physics.
Why do we have these specific laws governing everything? It feels strange to think they just existed from the beginning, especially during the Big Bang. Did they come about then, or were they always there, just waiting for something to happen?
It’s also unsettling that these laws seem so consistent throughout the universe. What if things could have been completely different? If there are other universes out there, do they have their own laws, or did we just get lucky—or maybe unlucky—with the way ours turned out?
I’ve come across some theories that try to address these questions. For instance, the multiverse theory suggests that there could be many universes, each with different physical laws. This raises the idea that our universe is just one possibility among countless others.
Then there’s the anthropic principle, which hints at the idea that the universe’s laws must allow for our existence; otherwise, we wouldn’t be here to ask these questions.
Additionally, some physicists explore concepts like string theory and quantum gravity, which propose deeper frameworks that might explain how these laws came to be or why they are so consistent.
I find myself wondering about all these things, and it’s kind of overwhelming. Does anyone else feel this way, or have thoughts on where these laws might come from?

See Nancy Cartwright's works and Laws of Nature.

If you are having an Existential crisis, you should do anything other than look further in to Philosophy.

Honesly: if your whole intellectual ontology is built on the widespread assumption that everything is always ultimately explicable by physicists, you should feel a little like the cartoon coyote who discovers that there's no ground under his feet. Not because something else explains everything, but because you need a whole different perspective.

"It’s also unsettling that these laws seem so consistent throughout the universe." I don't know if it helps but you should understand that this is primarily an assumption. In reality, we have no direct proof of this.

Somethings like gravity exists the way it does in order for our universe(s) to form.  If gravity to low planets won't form because the clouds of hydrogen won't produce enough gravity to attract enough matter to have a planet.  On the other hand if gravity is too high you will have to many blackholes and everything will be swallowed up.  The laws of gravity describe these relationships and there strengths and/or limitations as we know them.

Some of the laws of nature come from mathematical symmetry   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04ERSb06dOg

I had three years of physics at school (up to explaining Heisenberg, Einstein etc in principle, but not Maxwell which is bloody hard), and I could have become a physics graduate within four years, and a PhD in another three, and then that’s where learning starts. I don’t worry I don’t know it all, nor should you.

"It’s also unsettling that these laws seem so consistent throughout the universe."  If you are unsettled and having an existential crisis because of this you should consider that a great many people take hope and comfort in the notion that there is something beyond our comprehension responsible for all this.  As Scott Rowe commented above, you won't find any comfort in the cacophony of competing humanistic philosophies here...

There are some things we will never know, and questions we will never answer. ... And that's OK.

@Ben Why do we use "we" so often when making declarations?  I don't wish to be part of your "we" in this instance, if it means agreeing to admit defeat when it comes to gathering greater and possibly conclusive understanding of everything.  Can you exclude me from your "we" please.  You could go with "There are some things I will never know, and questions I will never answer... and that's OK" for example.

@AlistairRiddoch I also don't wish to be part of that group, but I am, willy-nilly. ... It's simply a fact of physics that we cannot know everything, at least in this life. Perhaps in the afterlife it will be different.

You ask:

Where do the Laws of Physics come from?

The short answer is they come from physicists because laws are statements or propositions and not the physical regularities of phenomena described by those laws themselves. They are a subset of the canons of scientific law because they deal in physical theory as opposed to chemical, biological, or psychological theory, for instance. However, be careful, because if you treat those laws as physically real things, then you are committing the reification fallacy. From WP:

Reification (also known as concretism, hypostatization, or the fallacy of misplaced concreteness) is a fallacy of ambiguity, when an abstraction (abstract belief or hypothetical construct) is treated as if it were a concrete real event or physical entity. In other words, it is the error of treating something that is not concrete, such as an idea, as a concrete thing. A common case of reification is the confusion of a model with reality: "the map is not the territory".

If you accept that laws are linguistic artifacts and are nomological constraints only in the sense they are part of a nomological conceptual network constructed by converting observations and experiments to language, then it's easy to explain their creation. The laws and theories of physics come from the scientific community and a collection of scientific methods, the question of whose identity was identified by Karl Popper as a philosophical problem known as demarcation. To understand how reliable scientific claims are produced requires a fair understanding of epistemology and philosophy of science and generally leads one on the path to a naturalized epistemology.
If you extend the question, though, by granting there are regularities in the universe, and then ask, why is there regularities at all, you are squarely in the territory of metaphysics which asks these questions about reality. Religious sorts have proposed God and gods of all sorts. If you can't accept the supernatural, you might want to consider that the Principle of Sufficient Reason is flawed. From WP:

The principle of sufficient reason states that everything must have a reason or a cause. The principle was articulated and made prominent by Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz, with many antecedents, and was further used and developed by Arthur Schopenhauer and William Hamilton.

Perhaps it makes no sense to ask about causes of the properties of the universe itself since the universe might be more a reflection of how our mind constructs representations than the things it constructs represents of. Kant famously posited his notion of the cognitively inaccessible Ding an sich; also, going back to the Ancient Greeks, one finds the notion of acatalepsy

When people talk about "the laws of physics" they almost always mean the characteristics of reality, not descriptions thereof. Distinguishing between the map and the territory is always useful, but there is a territory and that's what the phrase usually refers to.

@gs You can produce a dictionary or encyclopedia entry to substantiate your claim?

nope, apparently "laws of physics" doesn't get any dictionary entries whatsoever. I'd suggest just asking the OP what he means.

When I argue that "reality" is ultimately a mystery it is not popular in this forum. It gets a few votes here and there. But in essence you have stated that mapping our human concepts and perceptions to reality is a reification fallacy! Can I perform any experiment to prove to myself that reality has the attributes that I map to natural events and to social agents arising in my mind? No! But I still feel compelled to treat certain attributes of natural events and social agents as "real" apart from my models or rather I strive to continually improve my models of natural events and human agents!

@SystemTheory No. I am arguing that concepts and perceptions are not physical reality. Not all of reality is physical, unless you're an material eliminativist. It is a category mistake to assert that logical propositions (and the ideas conveyed by language) are physical things. They have physical being (called the medium), but they are largely mental objects.

I did not state that reality refers exclusively to physical or material attributes. If you argue that reality has physical and non-physical attributes then that is entirely consistent with my view that mental models of reality cannot in any way be verified as the actual attributes of ultimate reality. Unless you argue that reality reduces to what exists in the mind then reality is not a great mystery it is what arises and passes away in the stream of human consciousness. Models of physical and non-physical reality arise and pass away in the stream of human consciousness.

Is it accurate to say that it makes no sense to ask about causes of the properties (laws) of the universe because these properties are themselves describing causality and therefore such attempts could lead to the cause of our description of  those properties (which are what we name "laws") but not the actual causes of the underlying phenomena which we are trying to describe?

@Andy Now you are in the thick of it. Are properties beyond our descriptions of them as linguistic laws and theories real, and to what extent? Classical thinking says they are absolutely real and is called scientific realism. Starting in earnest with Duhem and in line with Kant's Ding an sich metaphysics moves towards instrumentalism. Surely some theories and laws have been shown to be wrong, so yes, sometimes when we identify a "cause"...

we have not really identified a "cause". Laws can be superseded by better laws. Consider Netwonian gravitation which was replaced by relativistic gravitation. The fact known since at least Hume is that science works by induction and inference to best explanation, and both of those suffer from the scandal of induction. Therefore, Kant's noumenon is vindicated.

@gs "When people talk about 'the laws of physics' they almost always mean the characteristics of reality, not descriptions thereof."  In all fairness, when people talk, they almost always are not using terms with the precision demanded by philosophy.

I think it's important to distinguish between 1) laws that are formalized by human scientists and represent an approximation or model of nature; and 2) the true laws of nature, that actually are the case. It's not obvious that the latter exist at all, since all we can access is the former, the inventions of men, and Kant tells us that we will never reach or access the things in themselves: we can only access phenomena ie the way things look.
A better question therefore would be: Are there laws of nature, and if yes, where do they come from?
As an atheist, I would answer "no" to that question. There are IMO certain ways in which the universe behaves, and some regularities therewith, but not laws in the sense of precise directives given by a sapient entity.
For a believer, the question is of course much easier to answer: "God said so".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The question, where the laws of nature come from, transcends our cognitive capabilities. Until now no one has made a general accepted proposal.
Science only deals with the natural laws discovered in our universe, not with their origin. Thoughts about the multiverse are fascinating and open up a wide range of fantasy. But until now they are speculations, not scientific theories.
To not lose the ground under your feet you may study some textbooks from physics and cosmology, not restricting to just the last trend from popular books on physics on the market.
Added: Bibliography.

Feynman, Richard; Leighton, Robert; Sands, Matthew: The
Feynman-Lectures on Physics. Vol. I, Chap. 1-3, Vol. III, Chap. 1.
Feynman, Richard: QED - The Strange Theory of Light and Matter.
Weinberg, Steven: The Quantum Theory of Fields. Vol. I, Chap. 1.
Weinberg, Steven: The First Three Minutes.
Esfeld, Michael : Philosophie des Sciences. Une Introduction. (Deutsch:
Einführung in die Naturphilosophie. 2. Aufl.)


Your two mentions of "until now" is tantalizing and your directing the reader to physics & cosmology textbooks is merely suggestive.  Can you be more specific on what's the latest and/or a book title (for illustration)?

@GratefulDisciple I added some bibliography. Sometimes I recommend selected chapters, not the whole book. The whole book could be quite challenging because addressing the expert.

Thanks.  No wonder Feynman lectures are popular.  Heard Weinberg mentioned a lot too.

You used the tag physics, so in that context the answer to your question

Why do we have these specific laws governing everything?

is "we do not know, and we do not care". The end.

This blunt answer is, again, from the perspective of a physicist. We measure things, we model things and we try to fit what we measure to our model. If this does not work we change the model.
There is no question in science "where did [it] come from" if this is not linked to measurement and models. Otherwise we leave the realm of science and move to philosophy, guessology or other non-science-based ologies.
I understand that this is a SE Philosophy and that there will be very good answers from that perspective - but since you elected to use physics I added the scientific approach to your concerns.

The closest physicists come to philosophy is when we talk about "interpretations". There are some weird physics laws that can fit to several models.
An example is the many-worlds interpretation of some complicated quantum effects where physicists try to guess where they come from. So how different is this from a religious quest for answers to things we do not understand? It is because we say

We have an effect we measure. We do not have a theory why it happens this way. Let's imagine it is because of XYZ (wildly guessing, with lots of handwaving). Now that we have that assumption, let's see if by going from XYZ we can predict some other events. If we cannot predict, let's check if everything that we measure fit in that model. If it does not we trash the model and look for a better one.

We do not try to forcibly give an answer to something we do not know. We do that to predict or confirm other measurable stuff.

For one, you seem to think that you speak for all physicists, but in actual fact you do not. You're just speaking for your little self, like everybody else. For two, it is rather obvious that metaphysical questions such as the OP's go beyond physics. They wouldn't be called "metaphysics" otherwise. For three, what makes you think that your lack of interest in metaphysics is interesting to other folks? Do you often go to websites devoted to poker just to tell other folks there that you don't play poker and never will, because it's a stupid game?

@Olivier5: Re 1 - of course I speak for myself. It is like saying" in philosophy we ...". Bu worry not - you can switch all "we"s to "a finite group of at least one element". Re 2: it is not obvious at all. There is a tag physics so I am speaking of physics. You can do the metaphysical part which I have no idea about. I have no idea why you aggressively assume that I want to force my answer when nobody wants it. I am providing the physical aspect to a question labeled with physics. Feel free to post your own. Or flag it as out of scope, or spam, or whatever you feel it is.

Okay so it was a sort of "royal we" you were using... :-)  What I find most amusing, is the urge to comment on a metaphysical question by saying something which amounts to "I look down on metaphysics", ie a self-contradictory metaphysical statement.

@Olivier5 there is no urge - just a perspective from physics when there is a "physics" tag. No looking down either - this is something like poker: I am not interested so I do no care. It is certainly not a topic worth arguing about because everyone can have their own opinions until they do not pose a risk. If it was about homeopathy, though... :)

Everybody doesn't care about metaphysics, until they meet one of these questions that won't go away. See the OP first sentence for an illustration. Maybe you haven't been there yet.

@Olivier5 WoJ is speaking for a very large number of physicists, not just for himself. Please remove that phrase from your vocabulary anyways. It's insulting, and has the effect of scaring causious people into submission. That's exactly those people who should be heard the most. And it's exactly those people who use tactics like "you are just speaking for your little self" who should get the least attention, imho.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica For how many physicists does he talk for then? How many physicist did he or you speak with about these matters?

@Olivier5 Enough.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica I will concede that metaphysics are often said to be a waste of time in scientific circles, but that to me is little more than a posture, because scientists too ask themselves these bizarre questions, and they care enough about them to debate them on philosophy sites... and one based on a inaccurate view of what metaphysics is really about, which discards it as "what cannot be measured". But metaphysics are about framing, grounding, justifying, and motivating human enquiry. It's about why one needs to measure in the first place, prior to the act of measuring.

And that's why the answer to these questions cannot be measured.

Oddly, the largest institute for theoretical physics in the world, as their mission statement "Our mission is to advance understanding of the universe at the most fundamental level, stimulating the breakthroughs that could transform our future. We foster developments in foundational theoretical physics through scientific research, training, and educational outreach." --- Makes it sound like they don't know but DO care.

@AlistairRiddoch What I meant by "we do not care" is that there is no will to forcibly have an answer. In other words, when physicists cannot explain something, they would say "there will come a time when we understand, in the meantime we are building models either for this thing, we do not understand (and test them) or for other things and, maybe, they will collaterally give an explanation to that thing we do not understand". Yet in other words, when X is unknown, we do not say "we have to say something, so let's make it that X is because [some random belief]"

@WoJ I dunno... "Dark Energy" and "Dark Matter" are pretty dubiously founded suggestions.  In a way I get it... saying "stuff undetermined which causes these observed effects, in "this way" mathematically... is cumbersome.  We like giving things names.

The "Laws of Physics" can mean one of two things.

The laws as discovered by the science of physics, and taught in school and university.
The actual laws on which the universe operates.

These are not the same thing.
The Laws as Discovered
These are found by experiment, and can be calculated or approximated using mathematics.
As you will readily understand, only laws which are mathematically regular can be found in this way, as we rely on mathematics as one of the tools to discover them.
The Laws of Operation
It may be, as some assert, that the universe operates entirely according to mathematical rules.
But it is entirely possible there is much going on in the universe which obeys no mathematical rules whatsoever.
Since mathematics is for us an essential tool to discover the rules of the operation of the universe we would have no way of discovering if this is the case or not.
Discussion
Proposing that there may be some rules of the operation of the universe which do not obey any mathematical system is generally considered "Unscientific".
This is reasonable, as in this case we have no way of discovering these rules, or if someone were to suggest some such rule, we would have no way of determining if the question were correct - we need mathematics to determine this, and since the suggestion is the rule is not mathematical, we have no way to answer the question.
The usual formulation, often attributed to Popper, but related to the Austrian school of Logical Positivism, is that such questions are meaningless.
I don't think that's quite correct. Such questions are unanswerable, but that is not the same as meaningless.
Specifically:
If there are some laws of operation of the universe which cannot be modelled by any mathematics, it seems to follow that

we will never discover these rules using mathematics, and
therefore we can never know what these rules are, and
therefore there will always be an unpredictability about the universe.

Likely this has no practical effect - we are unlikely to ever arrive at "the end of physics" in any case, so what does it matter?
But that is not the same as saying it is a meaningless question - if it is true, then we can never arrive at "the end of physics" even in principle. That means something.
Personal note
I remember clearly as a small boy thinking about how plants grow. One day, I was sure, I would understand it in full detail!
I still do not, what is more no-one does.
Conclusion
We discover the laws of physics (or at least those that we do discover) using experimentation, and aided by mathematics. What we know is only a subset of what can be discovered using these methods.
How can we live with this?
We must make our peace with it. We have to get used to the fact that there will always be things we do not know, and be grateful for what we can know.

Lovely! Except the conclusion should be We discover a few laws... Or does your local meteorologist know the weather same day next year?

@Rushi I can't argue with your comment - perhaps I should have phrased it "We discover the laws of physics in the first sense, when we do, ..."

Nicely done. Tnx!

"I remember clearly as a small boy thinking about how plants grow. One day, I was sure, I would understand it in full detail!  I still do not, what is more no-one does." - I am pretty happy in my understanding.

There's actually an argument using the very things in this question called the transcendental argument for God's existence.  A good book using this argument is one by Jason Lisle called The Ultimate Proof of Creation.
Basically, in general, the transcendental argument goes something like this: To make any argument at all, we have to use logic.  To study science in any meaningful way, we must assume the uniformity of the laws of nature.  We take these things for granted.  However, without God, the fact that the laws of logic are so applicable, or that the physics laws are so uniform, really doesn't make sense.  In other words, we cannot explain why this is the case without God.  Some might argue that uniformity is part of the universe's nature; i.e., that matter, by very nature, behaves in a uniform fashion; but that doesn't answer the real question of why this is the case.  Another approach (pragmatic) might be to say that the laws of logic and uniformity "just work," and so we believe and use them.  However, neither side is challenging that the laws of logic work, or that the universe's laws are uniform; but again, the question is why.  (I'd say a pragmatic response to "why" is conflating epistemology with explanation.)  The transcendental argument would assert that without God, this question of why goes fundamentally unanswered.  And so, for example, a point of the transcendental argument would be that arguing against God's existence using the laws of logic and the uniformity of nature would be kind of like talking against the existence of air--one must use air in order to speak the very argument.
UPDATE: Per @JMac's observation that the original answer was too sparse, I've added some elaboration of the logic of the argument above.

How to support your claim that without God “these things” – do you mean the laws of nature? -  “really don’t make sense”? – Indeed, you can just investigate and find out the laws. Full stop. - Which sense you give to your life seems to me quite a different question.

@JoWehler Good point about the vague wording, I've clarified what I mean by changing the wording to, "However, without God, the fact that the laws of logic are so applicable, or that the physics laws are so uniform, really doesn't make sense."

Thanks for the clarification. Indeed, the question why “the laws of logic are so applicable” or why “the physics laws are so uniform” has found no answer. But posing a personal god as creator of the universe is no solution. The God-concept produces much philosophical trouble and follow-up questions with endless discusssions. See the history of philosophy, in particular European or Arabic philosophy of religion, notably theology.

@JoWehler I'd say that endless argument doesn't necessarily indicate a lack of clarity.  E.g., two nations might battle persistently over a piece of land, not because the national boundaries were unclear (though that may be given as a political reason), but often, simply because the land is so valuable.

Ok. You can have all the stuff from before the start of the universe, I won't fight you for it :-) Just don't bring it in to the present.

I think this answer needs to elaborate on why these things don't make sense without god.  That doesn't follow to me, there's no backing for it in the answer.  Why does uniform laws imply god?  If anything, I would think the breaking of physical laws would be better evidence of god, since that would at least imply something has more causal power than the laws themselves.

@JMac Good idea about adding more detail there, I'll see if I can find Lisle's book tonight and get an excerpt or something.  As for miracles, perhaps you're right that those would be better evidences, though I'd say that to be discernible, they'd need to be against a backdrop of general natural uniformity.  And so I think that both the laws, and the superceding of them, can be great evidences simultaneously, just in different ways.

Not bad.  It is probably the only real answer (i.e. the most logical, consistent, believable) to the question.

@JMac I've tried to flesh out the logic generally used in this argument a bit more, thanks for the suggestion.

The real problem with this answer as hinted by @JoWehler, is this: Going from Law to God is ok; going from God to personal God less so. Note for example, Spinoza's God IS Law(fulness). A personal God is a very peculiar assumption of (mainstream) Christianity. ("Mainstream" because notable Christians like Meister Eckhart contradict this. Consider this as a deist comment though I don't really fit these inherently Christian categories)

I still find this argument quite lacking, it almost seems like a god of the gaps argument.  Saying the "why" is just god would only be an argument with explanatory power if it's already established god exists. I dont see how essentially just stating "god answers the problem" actually provides any value or reflects any truth.  It also is not that remarkable to me that we have consistent rules/laws.  We choose them because they are consistent, that's like the main value of the concepts.  Its not surprising to me that methods we developed for their consistency are consistent.

@JMac I feel like under that standard, though, most "best explanation" arguments could be characterized as being "of the gaps" in a way.  E.g., I've heard evolutionists say that they'd welcome a better naturalistic theory of life than current Darwinian evolution if it was found, and that science loves to prove itself wrong, etc.  That is to say, Neo-Darwinian evolution is currently the best explanation (in their view).

As for consistency, I don't think the argument is that it's remarkable that our rules are consistent, as I think you correctly point out; but that they're so consistent and applicable, and applicable at such complexity and precision.  True, we can (and do) choose consistent rules, but we can't choose a consistent universe.  I.e., if the universe were a junkyard mess, we could choose consistent rules as we please, but they would be mere impractical ideals with trivial real world value.

The second sentence is where it turns into nonsense.

Peter Take e = mc^2. There is no formula that is similar but slightly different and makes any sense.

@gnasher729 By "second sentence," are you referring to, "To study science ..."?  True about e = mc^2.  I think the argument is that it's remarkable, if we step back from science and look at it philosophically, that reality should be such that nature behaves so uniformly and strictly according to laws and formulas like that.  I.e., philosophically speaking, why isn't nature more of a "Wild West" incapable of description by such elegant laws and formulas?

Well worth pointing at the First Mover argument which runs along similar lines.

What sort of answer would satisfy you?
There are some things we may be able to explain. For example Gravity is a lot weaker than all the other forces. Recently there were theories that tried to tie gravity to entropy on some microscopic level. That hasn't come to anything yet, or it would be big news. But this would not explain the other forces. At some point, you end up with 'well, that's the way it is', right?
We may come up with an explanation which has particularly pretty equations. In the seventies, some early string theory models with 12 dimensions had a particularly pleasing form, but they did not come close to predicting things such as the actual size and age of the universe. To do this, they had to add an extra dimension, and string theory lets you add all sorts of constants. It is still possible that there is a unique theory of everything with particularly beautiful maths out there. However, this is the sort of solution that theoretical physicists tend to look for first.
There is the Anthropic Principle applied to multiple universes. If there are infinite universes with every possible set of laws, then a universe where life can evolve would be certain.  If you could provide some evidence for the other universes, then that would be fair game. But it is not fair to postulate an infinite number of other universes, so your particular one becomes likely.
God has been suggested as a primal cause. In some ways, this argument shows how stuck we are. We are within the universe, and cannot go outside it, and ask why universes are put together like that. I do not believe in God because I have an effective disproof of their existence. I do not believe in God, because I find it is an unhelpful idea that does not explain or prove anything. If it did, then I might.
In the end you are stuck. The explanation of the universe, if there is one at all, would seem to lie outside the universe, as per Wittgenstein's 'Tractatus'.

The Anthropic Principle doesn't depend on the possible existence of multiple universes.

@D.Halsey That's right. The Anthropic principle can be applied at the planetary scale: if there are enough stars with planets, life is likely to happen somewhere. But the question suggests an Anthropic principle applied to Universes. This is valid, but unhelpful.

I think a better way to think about the "laws of science" is first to consider a scientific theory. A scientific theory is a well-supported and rigorously tested framework that explains how various phenomena in nature are connected. Theories are developed by synthesizing all available data from observations and experiments to create a cohesive explanation. You can think of them as the "big pictures" in science.
Importantly, no theory is perfect; some may be more accurate or useful than others, but science strives to develop better theories over time. A key point to understand is that everything in science falls under one or more theoretical frameworks.
So, what are laws? Scientific laws are concise statements or mathematical descriptions that summarize a consistent relationship observed in nature but only within the boundaries defined by a theory. For example, Newton's three laws of motion describe the behavior of objects under the theory of classical mechanics, but they break down when we move into the theories of quantum mechanics and general relativity. Similarly, Ohm's law, which falls under the theory of electromagnetism, describes the relationship between voltage, current, and resistance, but it only applies under specific conditions.
I'm not aware of any law that is actually universally true. Every scientific law falls within a theory, and since no theory is perfect, no law will be perfect.

Short version. (Everything I say here can probably be found within some of the other answers if you have the time to read and absorb all of their minute details:)
Physical laws don't govern anything. What we call "physical laws" actually are just mathematical descriptions of how things always seem to behave. When something is called "physical law," that means, "we have always observed things to behave in this particular way, and we don't know why."
But Wait! Sometimes, explanations for older "physical laws" are found that depend on more recently discovered, deeper physical laws. We ought to strip the older formula of the title, "physical law" when that happens, and we should call it a theory instead. But people are sentimental. It's hard to get people to stop saying, "so-and-so's law" in those cases when so-and-so was a certified member of The Pantheon of Great Scientists.

Interestingly, Einstein's relativity is still referred to as theories, not laws, although they're as well confirmed as Newton's.

The laws of physics are human inventions. They're our attempt to make sense of and describe how the universe works.
The reason we're able to do this is because the universe is not totally random, it exhibits some regularities and consistencies. Because there are patterns, organisms are able to take advantage of them and devise behaviors that depend on them repeating. This is a fundamental requirement for any kind of organized life to emerge; if the universe were capricious, strategies that were developed would not work consistently enough to be useful (as an analogy, imagine trying to navigate a maze if someone keeps changing it randomly -- if you get out, it's just pure luck and anything you learn won't be useful the next time).
Most organisms have just adapted naturally to the patterns of the universe. But humans have gone beyond this. Our abilities to think and communicate about abstract concepts allow us create descriptions of these patterns. And when we collectively conclude that some descriptions are accurate enough, we called them "laws".
However, scientists have come to learn that it's hard, maybe impossible, for us to explain the most fundamental nature of the univese. We called Newton's discoveries of the mathematical patterns in motion and gravitation laws, but then came Einstein, who showed that they're just approximations to his theories of relativity that are accurate enough at low speeds and gravity. So we've become humble and stop calling these things laws -- It's been over a century with no significant change to Einstein's equations, but we still call them his "theories" of relativity. And when scientists look for a unification of relativity and quantum mechanics, they refer to it as a "grand unified theory" or "theory of everything" -- they no longer think that we're discovering true laws. Everything is just our best understanding at the time -- if there's a law, we can't be sure we'll ever discover it (or if we do, how could we know that there's not something even more fundamental underlying it?).

The laws of physics come from the human imagination. More specifically the domain of knowledge that we call Physics emerged historically as the product of a process of human communication. Humans interact and communicate via many modes of self-other communication. Physics is a special mode of self-other communication wherein we define and measure physical quantities. The laws of physics are statements that hold true within the specified context. Newton's law of gravity gave good results except for certain observed motion of Mercury. Einstein found some new laws of physics that describe the observed motion of Mercury. Newton's laws, also the Classical Laws, are considered valid within the specified limited context.
Galileo's law of horizontal motion, for example, held that a body projected at initial speed along an infinite horizontal plane would remain in motion at constant speed in the absence of resistance. His law of vertical motion held that a body would fall toward earth in uniform accelerated motion, independent of its weight, in the absence of resistance. These limited laws held valid in the context of Galileo's investigations but were not general enough to provide for general laws of physics.
Galileo specified measurement methods to define weight, time, position, change of time, displacement (change of position), speed, and acceleration. Newton defined momentum as the mass of a body multiplied by its velocity at an instant of time. Newton's first law of motion held that a body does not change its momentum, that is, it does not accelerate, unless it is acted upon by a net external force.
To specify position and displacement we need to apply a reference frame. To specify time and change in time we need to use a clock. The point is that all the concepts of physics, including the laws of physics, exist in our imagination when we use our body and mind to form concepts about our perceptions. Measurement methods enable us to form concepts about our perceptions of external reality. Patterns that seem to repeat and hold true in this context become laws of physics.
Problems in Classical Physics are solved using a generic paradigm. We recognize the quantities that do not change during an interaction between a system and its surrounding and we use those properties to solve for the quantities that may change or do change during the interaction. The interaction between a system and its surroundings, or the change within an isolated system, is called a natural process. We use the so-called Conservation Laws of Classical Physics to setup a differential equation. Then we use known quantities to solve for unknown quantities using the methods of Calculus. Quantities that are conserved in Classical Physics are mass, momentum, energy, and electric charge.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Mostly, this is a conceptual issue.

For the question, the laws of physics is a pleonasm. Physics is essentially a set of laws. So, the question becomes "where does physics come from". Remark that 'the laws of physics' (which opposite would be the contingencies of physics, where physics is discipline of knowledge) is radically different to 'physical laws' (which opposite is metaphysical laws). Here, we address the second figure.
Laws are rules, which are, essentially, relationships of qualia between two concepts. For example, 'the sky is blue' relates the concepts 'sky' and 'blue' in a univocal form (sky→blue, and not blue→sky). Rules are also known as judgements, in its rational conception. Likewise, judgements are just relationships between concepts (e.g. anna is timid). Some judgements seem not having two concepts to relate, like 'I dream', but such is just a simplification introduced by language: the explicit form would be something like I dream dreams, I sleep the sleep. Worst even, there are shorter forms, like the imperative "Go.", which explicitly would be "you, go to the destination".
Laws can be metaphysical or physical (e.g. 'thoughts are subjective' exceeds the physical world, so, it is metaphysical; 'the sky is blue' is physical).
According to Kant (c.f. Critique Of Pure Reason), Metaphysical laws are developed by Reason in order to allow experience. Logics and Mathematics are not directly related to the physical world, but Reason develops all logical and mathematical concepts in order to make experience possible. So, metaphysical laws come from reason.
Physical laws are equivalent; however, they are related not only to the metaphysical process, but to the physical process. Perhaps the first metaphysical law that we come to develop due to the need of Reason is that I, the physical subject, is different to the physical object. That is, if I grab an apple, my body keeps being my body, and the apple keeps being the apple.
Not all physical laws are written in books, for example, the previous one: the physical subject is independent of the physical object.
Ergo, physical laws are not only those described by formulae. Physical laws are judgements.
The physical laws that are described using mathematical language (formulae), are the result of centuries of trial and error. Once someone understood that, while apples are always different, they are still apples, and they can be added, he invented addition (probably we all do it in childhood). Probably other found ways to express such idea, using the fingers, and later, writing that in paper.

Voilà. That's the origin of physical laws, those that are written in books, and those that we all know subjectively, and for those we all agree about, those are the laws  we call objective.
